# Simulation stops after certain simulation time

Tags: anylogic

I have the problem that my model stops after a certain time and hangs. The simulation is then no longer operable and hangs.

I have already looked at AnyLogic under "Troubleshooting" and can not solve my problem.

Is there a trick how to find out what is not working in your model that it always stops at about the same place? I don't know where to start to fix my problem.

I noticed that I sometimes get error messages in the "Seize" block and that set parameters keep changing. Can it be related to this and how do I change the problem?

Thanks!

As I already mentioned I I have searched for my problem but have not found it.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the "maximum available memory" in your experiment properties, often it is just that.

Else, you may have created an infinite loop somewhere inadvertently. These are hard to debug. (hence always start with a simple model, test it, add a tiny feature, test it and repeat --> this way you can always tell what causes problems )

Comment: Increasing the maximum available memory didn´t help :( then there is probably an infinite loop somewhere..

Comment: Then strip back your model until it works, et voila: you found your issue (and start getting into the test-driven workflow above :) )